# How can I configure logging in Locust?

Tags: locust, python-logging

Using [locust](https://locust.io/) 1.4.1 and the documentation that talks about logging ([here](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/logging.html#skip-log-setup)) mentions that I can provide my own logging configuration with the `--skip-log-setup` option.

My issues are:

- When using `--skip-log-setup`, no logging appears and I've tried to add loggers in the test file but nothing works.
- Not using `--skip-log-setup`, I can't remove handlers with `logger.removeHandler(...)` b/c when I do `logging.getLogger('MyLogger')` nothing comes up, even though I created `'MyLogger'` by the time the test gets executed.

My code has its own loggers but I want **only** want the locust loggers in stdout (currently my logger is going both to stdout and file). I would like to *remove* the stdout logger from my code:

```
locust -f <my_file.py> --headless
```

Then in the Locust file:

```py
import logging
from locust import HttpUser
import my_class  # 'MyLogger' defined here with 2 handlers: file and stdout

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
handler = logging.handlers[1]  # 0 is file, 1 is stdout, but comes back as []!


class MyTest(HttpUser):
  blah
```

Hope this is making sense. Let me know if clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found something that works for what I need.

Run Locust with `--skip-log-setup`, which will make it so Locust doesn't have any logging.

```
locust -f my_file.py --headless --skip-log-setup <other params>
```

Then in the test file:

```py
# Set root logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel('DEBUG')

# Add stdout to locust logging
logger = logging.getLogger('locust')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```