# How could I choose Locust logs folder?

Tags: python, performance, testing, automation, locust

I know so far that by adding the `--csv` command I will get all the logs from a Locust run in headless mode (https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/retrieving-stats.html).
Now, is there a way to choose the folder where I want those logs to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried the `--logfile` option?
2. If that didn't work, you might need to create your own log handler. Have it be a `FileHandler` and you can specify the file.
   See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65118135/how-can-i-configure-logging-in-locust) around using `--skip-log-setup` and specify your own log handlers in the Locust file.
3. If you're spending too much time figuring that out, consider living with the functionality that the CSV files are saved in a fixed location and maybe have a post-run function that moves them somewhere else.

Comment: Oh! I just found out that you can add the path prior to the file name like `--csv folder/folder/filename`! but thanks for the help :D